# How to get SSE Last Event ID with CGI + Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lighttpd

I am using Server Sent Events (SSE) to push data to the front end. I was able to implement most of it just by researching its RFC https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-eventsource-20111020/. The only part I'm stuck on is if the SSE reconnects from a faulty connection.

The documentation says that when an SSE connection reconnects it adds the Last-Event-ID to the Header data. I have no idea how to get this from my script.

I am using lighttpd as my web server, cgi to run my scripts, and python 2.7 as my scripting language.

I attempted to read os.environ, but it does not contain anything related to the SSE last received ID.

Does anyone know how I can get the last event id received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out, so hopefully this will be useful for anyone in the future. The lastEventId is used silently in the back of the protocol. So, if the connection drops temporarily and then reconnects the lastEventId is used. All SSEs that were missed are queued up, and only the ones greater than the lastEventId are sent. However, if the connection permanently drops, or drops for longer than x minutes (browser dependent) then the SSE connection is terminated. A lastEventId will not be sent because it will be considered a new connection.

I was able to get around this by appending the lastEventId to the GET request of the SSE. So...

```
/var/www/SSE.py?lastEventId=100
```